# load bigfiles on PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpoffice

someone else know how load a bigfile on [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)?

too create a big file, because i use a [PHP_XLSXWriter](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter). when can create a big files with out overfloat the ram, but i would like know if anyone know if exist another metohd to work with big files on PHP Excel.

specific load files.

or if  [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) solve it

Thanks.

Comment: How big is your file before it won't work? 1Mb? 50Mb? 100Mb?

Comment: https://github.com/box/spout is the fastest I have seen for php, and it allows you to only read in a line at a time to avoid running out of memory. It's the best when working with larger files IMO

Comment: for example in PHP_XLSXWriter use a 250K and is possible configure to write a 1000k of row... and is great. but i would like know if is possible to don't use a memory ram on PHPExcel.

Comment: Perhaps [reading the PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md#cell-caching) would answer your question

Comment: PHPSpreadsheet still uses memory in the same way as PHPExcel..... that's what an "__in memory__" model requires